# Relationship one to one laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

i try it on this way but not dispalyed the relation

model Admission

```
public function dossierscocial(){
  return $this->hasOne('\App\Dossierscocial');
}
```

model Dossiersocial

```
public function admission(){
  return $this->belongsTo('\App\Admission');
}
```

in my view

```
@if(isset($admission->dossiersocials))
                    @foreach($admission->dossiersocials as $dossiersocial)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{$dossiersocial->id}}</td>
                            <td>{{$dossiersocial->user_id}}</td>
                <td>{{$dossiersocial->patient_id}}</td>
                <td>{{$dossiersocial->admission_id}}</td>

                <td>{{$dossiersocial->nationalite}}</td>

                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                    @endif
```

Comment: what i was thinking to do is One Admission = One Dossiersocial

Answer (score 0):

because `hasOne` return single object not `collection` so you can not use `foreach`.
there is just one object you can use it like this:

```
@if(isset($admission->dossiersocials))
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{$admission->dossiersocials->id}}</td>
                        <td>{{$admission->dossiersocials->user_id}}</td>
            <td>{{$admission->dossiersocials->patient_id}}</td>
            <td>{{$admission->dossiersocials->admission_id}}</td>

            <td>{{$admission->dossiersocials->nationalite}}</td>

                    </tr>
                @endif
```

or maybe you can use `hasMany` instead of `hasOne`